# cant get out from foreach loop

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

i got no idea why it cant get out from the loop after getting the properties and with the break statement.

```
int i = 2;

foreach (UITestControl con in uIItemCustom.GetChildren())
                {

                    Description = new HtmlCell(con);
                    Description.FilterProperties[HtmlCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIndex] = "4";
                    Date = new HtmlCell(con);
                    Date.FilterProperties[HtmlCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIndex] = "5";

                if (TestContext.DataRow["BillableLine"].ToString() == Description.InnerText.ToString() && TestContext.DataRow["Date"].ToString() == Date.InnerText.ToString())
                        {
                        HtmlSpan chk = FindControl<HtmlSpan>(x =>
                        {
                            x.Add(HtmlSpan.PropertyNames.Id, "timeMaterialGrid0_ctl0" + i + "_TriStateChkB");
                            x.Add(HtmlSpan.PropertyNames.TagName, "SPAN");
                        });
                        Mouse.Click(chk);
                        break;
                        }              
                    i++;         
            }
```

Comment: Use `return;` statement instead of `break;`

Comment: Put breakpoint on the 'break' statement and debug your code. Is the debugger stopped there?

Comment: I don't think return will work, as it is in a lambda statement. Consider making an extra method for this case or use gotos.

Comment: what is the next statement after break?

Comment: I'm sure if you put "else { break; };" it will break for loop.

Comment: @kennyzx the next statement is about the next action something like this 
 //click remove button
            Click("Criteria_btnRemove");

Comment: @VáclavStruhár yesh , it did stop there

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew i tried ... and then the increament is not working if i did that...

Comment: @user7755725 I just want to emphasis that something is wrong at "if" statement :)

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew anyidea to suggest ?>.<

Answer (score -1):

Please see my answer below, also [check this documentation](https://www.dotnetperls.com/break) to remember about C# break statement.

```
int i = 2;

foreach (UITestControl con in uIItemCustom.GetChildren())
                {

                    Description = new HtmlCell(con);
                    Description.FilterProperties[HtmlCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIndex] = "4";
                    Date = new HtmlCell(con);
                    Date.FilterProperties[HtmlCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIndex] = "5";

                if (TestContext.DataRow["BillableLine"].ToString() == Description.InnerText.ToString() && TestContext.DataRow["Date"].ToString() == Date.InnerText.ToString())
                        {
                        HtmlSpan chk = FindControl<HtmlSpan>(x =>
                        {
                            x.Add(HtmlSpan.PropertyNames.Id, "timeMaterialGrid0_ctl0" + i + "_TriStateChkB");
                            x.Add(HtmlSpan.PropertyNames.TagName, "SPAN");
                        });
                        Mouse.Click(chk);
                        break;
                        }
            // This is the part you need to add - an else and break
else{
  break;
}              
                    i++;         
            }
```

Comment: bro, the increament is not working if we code like that... the i is not increase...